# Is SELECT FOR ... UPDATE *necessary* to DELETE or UPDATE multiple rows without deadlock?

Tags: postgresql, deadlock, order-by, concurrency

Consider the following when the transaction isolation level is Read Committed (the default):

```
UPDATE example
  SET foo = 'bar'
WHERE ...
```

and

```
DELETE FROM example
WHERE ...
```

Neither `DELETE` nor `UPDATE` supports `ORDER BY`, nor do they have a defined order. After reading the PostgreSQL docs extensively, it would seem the most simple and reliable solution to avoid deadlock in a concurrent environment is

```
UPDATE example
  SET foo = 'bar'
WHERE ctid IN (
  SELECT ctid
  FROM example
  WHERE ...
  ORDER BY ctid
  FOR UPDATE
)
```

I'm not thrilled about doing this to every `UPDATE` and `DELETE` that affects multiple rows.

1. Is my assessment and solution correct?
2. Is this the best solution?
3. Is there a reason PostgreSQL doesn't already do this automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Your assessment is spot on, and there is no better way of doing it.

As an alternative, you could do without the sort, but delete in smaller batches, each in its own transaction. That is still susceptible to deadlock, but the likelihood is smaller, and re-running the transaction doesn't hurt quite as much.